# USing Join Information to get the information from the table

Tags: sql

I am new to the SQL. I am learning joins in query so that i eterive the information from the table using information. I am working in this question .

***Get the EmployeeNumber for the employees and the date they started any given department.***

Below is my table definition :

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
    EmployeeID      int         IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,EmployeeNumber int         UNIQUE
    ,DateOfBirth    datetime        NOT NULL
    ,FirstName      nvarchar(14)    NOT NULL
    ,MiddleName     nvarchar(14)    NOT NULL
    ,LastName       nvarchar(16)    NOT NULL
    ,DateHired      datetime        NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE Customers (
    CustomerID      int         IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,FirstName      nvarchar(14)    NOT NULL
    ,MiddleName     nvarchar(14)    NOT NULL
    ,LastName       nvarchar(16)    NOT NULL
    ,DateLastVisited datetime       NOT NULL 
    ,EmailAddress   nvarchar(52)    NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Departments (
    DepartmentID    int         IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,Code           nchar(4)        UNIQUE
    ,Name           nvarchar(40)    NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE DepartmentEmployees (
    DepartmentEmployeeID    int     IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,EmployeeID     int             NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT Department_Employee REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeID)
    ,DepartmentID   int         NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT Employee_Department REFERENCES Departments(DepartmentID)
    ,DateStarted    datetime        NOT NULL
    ,DateEnded      datetime        NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE Salaries (
    SalaryID        int         IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    ,EmployeeID     int         NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT Salaried_Employee REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeID)
    ,Amount     money           NOT NULL
    ,DateStarts     datetime        NOT NULL
    ,DateEnds       datetime        NOT NULL 
)
```

I have added the information by inserting the data accordingly to the table. 
For the question . 
I have written this answer but i am not sure wether it is right or not.

```
  SELECT e.EmployeeNumber, 
         d.DateStarted 
    FROM Employees e
    Right 
     Join DepartmentEmployees d
       on e.EmployeeID= d.DepartmentEmployeeID;
```

Comment: So, does your query ends up with the desired result? And also, why don't you just use an inner join as `Join` instead of `Right Join`?

Comment: Don't even consider RIGHT JOIN until you fully understand LEFT JOIN! It's much easier to understand `main table left join optional data`, instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Answer (score 0):

DepartmentEmployeeID is the primary key for the table department, you need to join the employee id's in both tables.

```
SELECT E.EmployeeNumber, D.DateStarted 
FROM DepartmentEmployees D 
LEFT JOIN Employees E 
ON E.EmployeeID= D.EmployeeID;
```